# How do i make an HTTPS version of my ReportServer?

Tags: ssl, reporting-services, https, reportserver, reserved

1. i have installed an SSL certificate on the relevant server
2. i approached the Reporting Services Configuration Manager-> Web Service URL in order to assign it a port 443
3. in addition to the port 80 i chose the SSL certificate under port 443
4. i clicked apply->  but only the http version works. although in the results it says that it reserved the https version as well.

am i missing a step in the middle that is preventing me from approaching the https?

Thanks,
Nachi

Comment: Do you have IIS installed on the same server? This can cause interoperability issues as detailed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nathan- Installing IIS on the server was the problem.
after i installed it, i changed the 'Rebind' settings to add port 443.

Thanks